# How do I use tramp to launch a remote PowerShell?

Tags: microsoft-windows, tramp, shell, remote

I'm trying to launch a PowerShell on a remote Windows system using `tramp`.  So far all I've been able to do is start a PowerShell inside Emacs on the local (Windows) machine.  What is the connection incantation to, from within Emacs, launch a PowerShell on a remote Windows machine?  I know how to use `tramp` to connect to a *nix system using ssh in the connection string, but I don't know what the syntax is for connecting to a Windows system (using `tramp`). Here is my elisp so far. What do I need to add to connect to a remote `machine`?

```
(defun remote-powershell (machine)
  "Run PowerShell on MACHINE."
  (interactive "smachine: ")
  (let ((explicit-shell-file-name "powershell")
    (explicit-powershell-args '("-file" "-")))
    (call-interactively 'shell)))
```

Answer (score 2):

The Tramp manual describes how to access a remote Windows machine. It uses Samba's `smbclient` program. A remote path looks like this: `/smb:user%DOMAIN@machine:/share/path/to/file`. The `%DOMAIN` part is optional. `share` is the name of a share on that machine.

However, this is only the first part. Samba does not support to run remote processes on a Windows machine. Years ago, I did integrate the call of `winexe` into Tramp for that purpose, and indeed, I could call a remote `powershell` from my local Emacs, running on GNU/Linux.

I haven't followed this last time, but there are messages that `winexe` cannot be compiled any longer with recent Samba. And I don't know of a replacement.

Anyway, you might study the Tramp manual, which describes what did run in the past:

```
(info "(tramp) Quick Start Guide: smb method")
(info "(tramp) External methods")
(info "(tramp) Remote processes")
```